# Why are there both printf and print in this command?

Tags: debian, awk, sed, printing, fail2ban

While studying about `fail2ban` I came across this command. I never worked with `awk` before, only with `sed`. I don't understand why there are both `printf` and `print`, there:

```
awk '{ printf "# "; print; }' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf | sudo tee /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

**Why are both there?**

<sub>BTW, if you know one, I invite you to share a sed version in the comments.</sub>

Comment: It's a clunkier way of writing `'{printf "# %s\n", $0}'`.

Comment: And, therefore, the sed version would be `sed 's/^/# /' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf | sudo tee /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `printf` is to append the character `#` to each line of the input file which in `awk` is represented by `$0` and then the modified line (with `#` added before) is printed out to the console using the `print` clause.

You could just ignore one and run it on the command line to see which one does what.

```
seq 1 5 | awk '{ printf "# "; print; }'
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

It could perhaps be simply written with `printf` alone or just with `print` alone as

```
awk '{ printf "# %s\n" , $0  }'
```

You need the new-line character `\n` because `printf` does not print it by default.

```
awk '{ print "# "$0  }'
```

Comment: One thing I miss: If `tee` also prints in console (and into a file), why do we need `print` when `tee` is there?...

Comment: You don't need tee(1), you need sudo(1) for the elevate permissions required to write under /etc. As written it's arguably safer than running awk(1) as root. (Additionally you can take the suggestion in this answer to test the command then append the privileged part after you're sure it works as intended.)

Comment: Alternatively `awk '{ print "#", $0 }'` with the default value of `OFS`.